# Как написать деструктор для класса, в котором одно из полей -- структура?

Tags: c++

На StackOverflow задавался [вопрос о том как написать простой связный список на C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141477/simple-linked-list-c). Там же был дан [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141477/simple-linked-list-c/22141970#22141970), в котором создается структура, как приватное поле класса. Вот код, который был приведен там:

```
class LinkedList{
    // Struct inside the class LinkedList
    // This is one node which is not needed by the caller. It is just
    // for internal work.
    struct Node {
        int x;
        Node *next;
    };

// public member
public:
    // constructor
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL; // set head to NULL
    }

    // This prepends a new value at the beginning of the list
    void addValue(int val){
        Node *n = new Node();   // create new Node
        n->x = val;             // set value
        n->next = head;         // make the node point to the next node.
                                //  If the list is empty, this is NULL, so the end of the list --> OK
        head = n;               // last but not least, make the head point at the new node.
    }

    // returns the first element in the list and deletes the Node.
    // caution, no error-checking here!
    int popValue(){
        Node *n = head;
        int ret = n->x;

        head = head->next;
        delete n;
        return ret;
    }

// private member
private:
    Node *head; // this is the private member variable. It is just a pointer to the first Node
};
```

Как написать деструктор для этого класса?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не совсем корректен. Если просто требуется удалить структуру, то можно воспользоваться оператором `delete`. Здесь же, другой случай и просто воспользоваться `delete` не получится. Нужно проходить по указателям. Как-то так:
`Node** q = &head; while (*q) { /* удалить текущий узел */ q = &(*q)->next; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставьте конструктор и деструктор в Node:

```
struct Node {
   Node() : next(NULL) {}
   ~Node() {if(next) delete next;}

   int x;
   Node *next;
};
```

В классе тоже самое, добавьте в деструктор строку:

```
if(head) delete head;
```

Тогда ноды будут удаляться при уничтожении объекта класса автоматом и рекурсивно.

**Update:**

```
int popValue(){
   Node *n = head;
   int ret = n->x;

   head = head->next;
   n->next = NULL;
   delete n;
   return ret;
}
```

**Update 2 (полный листинг):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList{
    // Struct inside the class LinkedList
    // This is one node which is not needed by the caller. It is just
    // for internal work.
    struct Node {
       Node() : next(NULL) {}
       ~Node() {if(next) delete next;}

       int x;
       Node *next;
    };

// public member
public:
    // constructor
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL; // set head to NULL
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        if(head)
            delete head;   
    }

    // This prepends a new value at the beginning of the list
    void addValue(int val){
        Node *n = new Node();   // create new Node
        n->x = val;             // set value
        n->next = head;         // make the node point to the next node.
                                //  If the list is empty, this is NULL, so the end of the list --> OK
        head = n;               // last but not least, make the head point at the new node.
    }

    // returns the first element in the list and deletes the Node.
    // caution, no error-checking here!
    int popValue(){
       Node *n = head;
       int ret = n->x;

       head = head->next;
       n->next = NULL;
       delete n;
       return ret;
    }

// private member
private:
    Node *head; // this is the private member variable. It is just a pointer to the first Node
};

int main() {
    LinkedList list;

    list.addValue(5);
    list.addValue(10);
    list.addValue(20);

    cout << list.popValue() << endl;
    cout << list.popValue() << endl;
    cout << list.popValue() << endl;
    // because there is no error checking in popValue(), the following
    // is undefined behavior. Probably the program will crash, because
    // there are no more values in the list.
    // cout << list.popValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не работает:
До: http://cpp.sh/9pye
После: http://cpp.sh/7aep

Comment: Метод popValue() доработайте.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Оставлю ссылку здесь на готовую версию, если вдруг кто потом зайдет: http://cpp.sh/6ijbc

Comment: Или, если ещё возможно, может отредактируете ответ? Код класса по ссылке http://cpp.sh/6ijbc вставьте в ответ. А то я что-то не уверен в сроках хранения кода на cpp.sh

Comment: @Abyx А как вы считаете правильно?

Comment: @Abyx Не то спросил, чем плохо `if(next) delete next`?

Comment: @Abyx, но у последней `Node` значение `next` равно `NULL`.

Comment: @Abyx, да, точно.

Answer (score 3):

Во первых там вовсе не структура, а указатель на неё. Это две большие разницы.

Во вторых не ясно что вы собственно собрались уничтожать если сам класс является просто оберткой для головы списка.

Думаю что проще определить в нем метод для удаления всего списка `clearList()`
с явным циклическим проходом по всем узлам и просто вызывать его в деструкторе.

P.S. Стоит иметь в виду что этот класс совершенно негоден для реального применения. Он явно зависит от типа данных элемента списка, в нем нет никакой обработки ошибок, конструкторов, полезных методов для итерации по списку. Там даже удаления произвольного элемента нет. На практике проще использовать `std::list`

Comment: Вопрос как раз касается циклического прохода по всем узлам. Я пытался написать это вот так: http://pastebin.com/UKQH5KtY

Comment: Ну логика правильная, надо брать следующий элемент и удалять предыдущий.

Comment: Но там какая-то проблема с указателями или скобки пропущены в первой строчке `p = &((*q)->next);`, Мне крайне лень думать над этим.

Comment: Вот так заработало: http://pastebin.com/fRx68rrz Спасибо!

Comment: @ssh: Если ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой.